# Web API Route Match Query Parameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to get Web API to handle the following request...

Note that `?name=` is a search query rather than retrieving a specific resource. So could also be `?name=xyz&city=Atlanta` or something like this.

`GET http://localhost/api/customer?name=xyz`

```
[Route("customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{name:alpha}")]        
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]string name)
    {
        return Json(name);
    }
}
```

If I remove `:alpha` from the route constraint this seems to work, otherwise I get a 404. I need to be able to constrain the query parameter (if this is even possible).

Or is there a better way to get Web API to match routes with query strings?

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute on the controller class be of type `RoutePrefix` instead of just `Route`?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
[Route("customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{name/alpha}")]        
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]string name)
    {
        return Json(name);
    }
}
```

And change the URL to:

```
GET http://localhost/api/customer/name/alpha
```

Comment: I want to use ? to denote a query against the customer resource. I've updated my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

From your query string, you're passing a value for name, so when you remove :alpha your query string matches with the route and it works.

change it to

```
[Route("customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("name/{alpha}")]        
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]string alpha)
    {
        return Json(alpha);
    }
}
```

Following would then work:

```
GET http://localhost/api/customer/name/xyz
```

OR

```
[Route("customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{name}")]        
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]string name)
    {
        return Json(name);
    }
}
```

then you would not need to specify name in your url, and you can call it like this:

```
GET http://localhost/api/customer/xyz
```

Comment: I've updated my question - I am looking to use what comes after the ? as a search query as opposed to a request for a specific resource.

Answer (score 0):

Your tag above your class should be [RoutePrefix] not [Route].  The way api routing works is /api/RoutePrefix/Route?parameterName=XXXX.  The routeprefix for your controller is "customer" and the route is "name" (as is the name of your parameter), so you'd want to do:

```
/api/customer/name?name=XXXX
```

So like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/customer")]
public class CustomerController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{name:alpha}")]        
    public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri]string name)
    {
        return Json(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have /api/customer?name=xxxx and have a route constraint for it ?